# Type java.lang.RuntimeException - Android 7 & 7.1

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Logs are copied from Play Store Console, There are no proper logs regarding this exception. It occurs only on Android 7 & 7.1.

I also tried Crashlytics but no logs are appearing for this exception.

What could be causing this error?  Is anyone facing the same?

[image]

Comment: You need to post the complete stacktrace, including the message.  According to the source code for Android 7, a `RuntimeException` is thrown when various things go wrong during app launching.  The nested stacktrace and the exception message will provide more information.

Comment: Actually, this is the problem, these are the complete logs nothing more is available on the console

Comment: Well in that case, the best I can suggest is that you look at the Android source code and see if you can work it out for yourself.  Here's the Android 7.0 version.  https://github.com/xdtianyu/android-7.0.0_r1/blob/4bd4cb29853dd0335dc1b04800bc5224f9232e31/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/ActivityThread.java

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47238636